# Can't sign in to Microsoft Account

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to unlock the visual studio community 2017. It said that I must sign in to unlock the product. But when I tried to sign in, I got this notification:

[image]

When I tried to add an account. I got this notification:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please go to https://login.live.comand check if you could log in successfully and try clearing the history files in your IE, then close all IE's and restart your pc to try again.

Besides, the problem may be also related to your Visual Studio itself. Please try repair your Visual Studio to check whether this problem can be fixed. You could also open Windows Explorer, and navigate to \Common7\IDE (by default is C:\Program Files or Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE), and run the following commands:

devenv.exe /resetsettings, it will restore Visual Studio default settings. Optionally resets the settings to the specified .vssettings file.
devenv.exe /resetuserdata, it will take a couple of minutes to run as Visual Studio cleans up and sets itself back to its original state.

Reference From: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/201565/sorry-we-ran-into-a-problem.html